# Docker compose dependant service ip and port is not accessible

Tags: mysql, docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm trying to run an integration service example(github [here](https://github.com/HubSpot/sample-apps-webhooks)) with below docker compose file which has a mysql service as a dependency for the main service

```
version: '2'

  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=events
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=events
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=events
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./db/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  webhooks_web:
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_LIST: kafka:9092
      KAFKA_GROUP_ID: events
      EVENT_TOPIC: events
      MYSQL_HOST: db
      MYSQL_DATABASE: events
      MYSQL_USER: events
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: events
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src/js/:/app/js/
      - ./src/public/:/app/public/
      - ./src/views/:/app/views/
      - ./index.js:/app/index.js
      - ./db:/app/db
      - ./tools:/app/tools
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command: ./tools/wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -t 60 --strict -- npm run dev
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This use the [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script to wait till mysql comes up. Script fails saying

```
wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 60 seconds for db:3306
```

My doubt is that the host name **db** doesn't get resolved into a ip. I'm not sure how this works but I checked the /etc/hosts file but that dns doesn't get added to there.

What is the problem here?

P.S - Log from the db service says it is ready to accept connections.

```
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:50.788673Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:51.340528Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:51.340583Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:51.343906Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:51.408233Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.32'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1            | 2023-03-19T09:32:51.408208Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
```

I can `docker-compose exec db /bin/bash` and use `mysql -u events -p` and log in to the server

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 and docker version is 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1

Comment: I do not think it is because of not resolving `db` service. Probably if it could not resolve, the error would be different. Try `docker compose exec webhooks_web sh` and `ping db` to see if it is resolved. Could you add `wait-for-it.sh` to the question?

Comment: @Andromeda
I could see following but ping didn't get a response

```
# ping db
PING db (172.18.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

`wait-for-it` is a rater long script. I have linked the github repo btw.

Comment: So it was resolved to 172.18.0.3 and It was not the root cause.  Maybe your db service was not functional at the moment. Is `db` healthy and ready to accept connection? Does db log show the client connection to see if the request has been reached to the db?

Comment: @Andromeda Log added to the question. Seems like db is ready. I can ssh in to `db` and log in the mysql server .

Comment: Please increase the timeout and see if it helped. Also, during start-up, run `nc -z db 3306` from `webhooks_web` container and see if it connects.

Comment: @Andromeda increase timeout didn't help. nc is not available so I tried `timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/db/3306 && echo Port is open || echo Port is closed' || echo Connection timeout` and it results `Connection timeout`. I tried another approach as per article https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/docker-compose-wait-for-container-using-wait-tool/docker-compose-wait-for-mysql-container-to-be-ready/ and there also same result. I wonder if something from mysql has changed.

Comment: I think you might have some firewall rules on the host that block the packets.

Comment: @Andromeda I added the github link if you don't mind giving it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was a issue with my docker installation. I had docker installed via `snap`. I checked the network and it seems like database and the app was in same network. Then when I tried to ping from container to container or container to ip both failed. I saw in one thread that docker installtion via `snap` can be faulty so decided to remove it and use apt to install and then network worked as expected.